# Logical Operators in Java Properties File

Tags: java, properties, logical-operators

Are there any recommendation for design patterns for using logical operators in conjunction with values generated from Java properties file (the number of values not known in advance)?

Comment: Is this question about [logical lines](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.Reader%29)? In any case, please clarify.